# Error validating S3 bucket name: only lowercase alphanumeric characters and hyphens allowed in "$var.bucket"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-modules

This is the detailed error I get after terraform apply

```
│ Error: Error validating S3 bucket name: only lowercase alphanumeric characters and hyphens allowed in "$var.bucket"
│
│   with module.s3.aws_s3_bucket.b,
│   on modules/s3/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
```

This is main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "$var.bucket"

  tags = {
    Name        = "$var.tag"
    Environment = "$var.environment"

  }

}
```

This variables.tf

```
variable "bucket" {
  description = "The Dev Environment"
}

variable "tag" {
  description = "Tagging the bucket"
}

variable "environment" {
  description = "Environment of the bucket"
}
```

This is module's main.tf

```
module "s3" {
  source = "./modules/s3"

  environment = var.environment
  bucket      = var.bucket
  tag         = var.tag

}
```

I tried fixing the error however I don't understand the error because everything seems perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
  bucket = "$var.bucket"
```

it should be

```
  bucket = var.bucket
```

also the devault value for the bucket is wrong and does not satisfy [s3 naming requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html). Try with:

```
variable "bucket" {
  description = "the-dev-environment-434331"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help however I get one more error although I am using a unique bucket name..... ```Error: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyExists: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
│       status code: 409, request id: MH2QB5BPDYQGA15J, host id: c4ka9wt9eF3Za+5RuJX6u2/2zGNQBn+XMpv8RiGPMyHtoIK/yzXwqQZjt8JjpsRqx3vvjOJ1qwQ=
│
│   with module.s3.aws_s3_bucket.b,
│   on modules/s3/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b ```

Comment: @Ak361 If you have new error, then new SO question should be asked.

Comment: I have checked by changing region as well however the error remains the same

Comment: I have changed aws account as well however get the same error                       ``` Error: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyExists: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system ```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin it got fixed. While using second account I was using underscore in the bucket and accordingly changed it to hypen ....it worked

Comment: Just as a comment: bucket names are globally unique. That means that it was previously created in any AWS account you will not be able to reuse the same name.